# MySQL stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am using mysql 5.0. I have a stored procedure which gets all the metadata of the database in a string and returns it. In it i call another stored procedure to get the metadata of the tables. I am using the following to get the list of schemas and their tables in a string

```
DECLARE tb_cur CURSOR FOR SELECT table_name, table_schema FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;
```

To this i am attaching the fields metadata by calling another stored procedure:

```
call Getfields(tbNm, dbNm, fields);
```

fields has been declared as:

```
Declare fields blob default "";
```

I then concatenate all to get a single string:

```
set output = concat(output, dbNm, ".", tbNm, "*", fields);
```

dbNm and tbNm are declared as

```
varchar(50)
```

The output in my getFields stored proc is of type `out fields blob`

The output from my main procedure is `OUT output blob`

When I run the getfields separately it returns the field data for a table, but when i call it from within my main procedure it returns a 1406 error data too long for coltype on row 16!!!
I saw that the type of column_type field in the columns table is long text so I have made the concatenation variable type blob.

Any hints/ suggestions ??
I have been stuck with this for a couple of days!!

--
query

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(table_info SEPARATOR '~') table_info FROM (
  SELECT CONCAT(t.table_schema, '.', t.table_name, '*', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(c.column_name, '+', c.COLUMN_TYPE) SEPARATOR ','))
   table_info 
  FROM information_schema.TABLES t
    JOIN information_schema.COLUMNS c
    ON t.table_schema = c.table_schema AND t.table_name = c.table_name
   GROUP BY t.table_name
   ) t;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More easy way, just run it -

```
SET @db = 'test'; -- Specify your schema

SELECT CONCAT(t.table_schema, '.', t.table_name, '*', GROUP_CONCAT(c.column_name)) table_info FROM information_schema.`TABLES` t
  JOIN information_schema.`COLUMNS` c
    ON t.table_schema = c.table_schema AND t.table_name = c.table_name
WHERE t.TABLE_SCHEMA = @db
GROUP BY t.table_name;
```

---

**Edit**

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(table_info SEPARATOR '\r\n') table_info FROM (
  SELECT CONCAT(t.table_schema, '.', t.table_name, '*', GROUP_CONCAT(c.column_name)) table_info FROM information_schema.`TABLES` t
    JOIN information_schema.`COLUMNS` c
      ON t.table_schema = c.table_schema AND t.table_name = c.table_name
  WHERE t.TABLE_SCHEMA = @db
  GROUP BY t.table_name
  ) t;
```

Comment: dont know why the internal call to a stored procedure was giving an error but all that ends well is well!! i used the query as a cursor and created a comma separated string and it does not have any problem! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You still can avoid using cursors, have a look at edited query.

Comment: yes i used the edited query without cursor. but it returns only a single tables data. I want all databases' all queries, if i only run the inner query it shows me all the rows for all the tables from all the databases but after adding the outer group concat only a single table data is shown .My query is in the edit.

Comment: i think the result is curtailed due to group_concat_max_len

Comment: You are right about the 'group_concat_max_len' variable; try to execute this statement before selecting - 'SET @@session.group_concat_max_len = 100000;'

Comment: i did that with the value 4294967295 ! longblob length!

Answer (score 0):

i think the result is curtailed due to group_concat_max_len. so i set it to the size of 4,294,967,295 (medium blob) and now it shows all the data.